# Сменить версию ASP.NET Core 2.2.0 на 2.2.3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

1) Как сменить версию (MS.AspNetCore.App + MS.NETCore.App) 2.2.0 на 2.2.3.
в global.json по умолчанию версия 2.2.300.

1.2) не понимаю зачем выпускать 2.2.3 когда в прокте ставится только 2.2.0

2) в NUGET есть MS.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 но нет NetCoreSdk 2.2.5 (есть только Runtime 2.2.5) Это как понять? зачем в тогда MS.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 в nuget?

В скриншоте есть Описание проекта и sdk. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все же гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - вопросы нужно задавать по одному и они должны быть конкретными. Наверное  вопрос "...не понимаю зачем выпускать 2.2.3 когда в прокте ставится только 2.2.0..." не имеет отношения к делу :).

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов По мне так, нормальный вопрос о расхождении версий различных компонентов.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov ну без риторических вопросов наверное все же можно обойтись. Чем короче текст- тем лучше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Референсы на Microsoft.AspNetCore.App и Microsoft.AspNetCore.All используют [неявное версионирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#implicit-version-for-some-package-references). Версия определяется в момент сборки, студия просто не заморачивается и всегда показывает 2.2.0.

Реальная версия сборок из Microsoft.AspNetCore.App зависит от используемого SDK, у вас это будет скорее всего SDK 2.2.300 и рантайм 2.2.5.